# value of an integer changes out of nowhere

Tags: c

I am trying to run the code below whilst using the debugger. At the end of the following loop "`for (i=0;i<n;i++) pin[i]=0;`", n's value changes from the value I've given it and becomes 0. I can't understand why that happens, so your help as to why it happens would be greatly appreciated. Oh, and one other thing. If I ignore it and as soon as I've given n a value, I assign that value to another integer, in order to be able to use it when n becomes 0, my program crashes. It's a crash of the type you get when, for example,  you're using a variable you've not assigned a value to.

```
main()
{
    int i,j,k,n,pin[n];
    printf("Give the size of the array:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    do{
        printf("Give the number of the iterations:\n");
        scanf("%d", &k);
    }while (k<1||k>n);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        pin[i]=0;
    for (j=0;j<k;j++){
        for (i=0;i<n;i++){
           if (i%j==0){
               if (pin[i]==0)
                   pin[i]=1;
               else
                   pin[i]=0;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ", pin[i]);
}
```

Comment: Your code exhibits Undefined Behaviour because `n` is uninitialised when you define `pin[n]`. Move the definition of`pin` further down, past the loop where you input and validate `n`.

Comment: Your title shows you have encountered Undefined Behavior out of nowhere. You have been puzzled that the machine does something quite at random, which you never told it to do. Unfortunately, this is mostly the result of a discrepancy between what you _want_ it to do and what you _told_ it to do. Debuggers help you analyze the latter until it conforms to the former. Merry Christmas everybody.

Comment: Yeap, that was it, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

You must not divide by 0 and define `pin[n]` where `n` is initialized.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, k, n;
    printf("Give the size of the array:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int pin[n];
    do {
        printf("Give the number of the iterations:\n");
        scanf("%d", &k);
    } while (k < 1 || k > n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        pin[i] = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < k; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (j != 0 && i % j == 0) {
                if (pin[i] == 0)
                    pin[i] = 1;
                else
                    pin[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", pin[i]);
}
```

Test

```
Give the size of the array:
3
Give the number of the iterations:
2
1 1 1
```

Test 2

```
Give the size of the array:
5
Give the number of the iterations:
4
1 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice! The code runs smoothly now!